# How to force AWS SAM CLI to detect changes?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

Amazon's SAM CLI does not pick up changes without rebuilding.  The documentation SOUNDS like I should not have to start/rebuild/restart every time I make a change to a function.  In fact, issuing the `sam local start-api` command provides the following message...

```
You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your 
functions, changes will be reflected instantly/automatically.  
You only need to restart SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template.
```

However, changes are *not* detected automatically.  So, changing *this*...

```js
const test = async (event, context) => {
  const body = JSON.parse(event.body || {});
  return toResponse(body);
};
```

... to this ...

```js
const test = async (event, context) => {
  const body = JSON.parse(event.body || {});
  body.date = new Date();
  return toResponse(body);
};
```

... **should** cause the `body` variable to include a `date` property.  Unfortunately, the only way to force this is to stop (`CTRL+C`), and then ...

```sh
sam build
sam local start-api
```

This is torture as the `sam build` takes almost a minute on a 32GB i7 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem of time to build, rather than building the whole template file just build the Lambda that you have made changes to.

```
sam build <FunctionName>
sam local start-api
```

The  should be the same as the one you specified in the template.yaml.

Comment: Thanks, but the goal is to cause the AWS SAM CLI to detect changes and handle them automatically as the CLI announces it will.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by **NOT** running `sam build` and instead just run `sam local start-api`. If you have run `sam build` delete the `.aws-sam` folder, then run `sam local start-api` again, or `sam local invoke...`. That should hot-load the latest code each time!

Also note the sam output hints towards this as well:
`"You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions, changes will be reflected instantly/automatically. If you used sam build before running local commands, you will need to re-run sam build for the changes to be picked up. You only need to restart SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template"` it fails to mention deleting the folder so you don't have to rerun `build` each time.