# Using AWS SAM-CLI requires rebuild every time I update the code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am using SAM CLI to develop an API Gateway Lambda proxy integration. According to the docs, I should be able to use `sam local start-api` to test my endpoint locally. The `start-api` command allows for "hot reloading" as [described in the AWS SAM documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-start-api.html). However, I am not seeing this behavior.

My `template.yaml` file looks like:

```yaml
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      DockerContext: ./hello_world
      DockerTag: python3.9-v1
```

When I run:

```sh
> sam build && sam local start-api
```

I can see that the endpoint is working:

> Mounting HelloWorldFunction at http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello
> You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions, changes will be reflected instantly/automatically.

However, when I make changes to the `lambda_handler` function inside of `./hello_world/app.py`, the response to `curl http://localhost:3000` remains the same. **No hot reloading occurs.**

The only solution I have found was to run `sam build` for each code change. This dramatically slows down development time -- because of some dependencies inside of `requirements.txt`, I have to wait 1-2 minutes for the build for each code change. I could just work on the file in the `.aws-sam/build` directory -- [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67137419/sam-run-without-rebuild) -- but this seems like a bad solution because I would have to maintain two copies of the handler simultaneously.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at this new beta release that allows for faster deployment cycles. It does talk about cloud deployments though and not local deployments. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/accelerating-serverless-development-with-aws-sam-accelerate/

Comment: Check out the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75104075/444578

Answer (score 11):

A great solution to this problem is to use the `skip-pull-image` flag so that Docker will reuse the Lambda runtime. Essentially run:

`sam local start-api -t template.yaml --skip-pull-image`

This got hot reloading working for me.

Comment: The reason it works:
AWS documentation: If you specify the --template option, AWS SAM CLI's default behavior is overridden, and will load just that AWS SAM template and the local resources it points to.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-api.html

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/920 & https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/901,  you are expected to have two consoles/terminals open.  One where you run `sam local start-api` and leave it alone.  And another where you run `sam build` repeatedly (whenever you need to update).

If you find this > slightly annoying,

- see https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/901#issuecomment-650629408
- upvote https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/921

Answer (score 1):

I used to find it quite annoying to be running two terminals and having to repeatedly build. Hence I ended up writing a boilerplate that bundles my source code and dependencies into a `dist` directory, runs `sam local start-api` in parallel, and watches for changes to update the `dist` directory.

Here's the repo: https://github.com/zishanneno/aws-typescript-lambda-boilerplate

Developing and debugging with this is much faster compared to building manually on every little code update.

Answer (score 1):

If a build exists, then `sam local start-api` uses built files to host the local version.
Simply delete the ".aws-sam" folder and run your`sam local start-api` again.
If ".aws-sam" folder does not exist, all your changes will be applied automaticaly.